# How do I perform an action after an UpdatePanel updates?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

When I have a regular textbox in a UpdatePanel (not an ASP.NET control) with some JavaScript events on it, after the UpdatePanel updates my events are gone. Is there a way to re-attach my events after the update? (Preferably without putting my events inline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [endRequest](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys.WebForms/PageRequestManagerClass/PageRequestManagerEndRequestEvent.aspx) event of the [PageRequestManager](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys.WebForms/PageRequestManagerClass/default.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `setInterval()` loop on document load that would search for the element in the update panel and if it didn't have the events, it can re-attach them.

Answer (score 0):

The events are gone because your textbox is a new element in the DOM (after the UpdatePanel refresh). As said by [korchev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159252/how-do-i-perform-an-action-after-an-updatepanel-updates#159330), use the endRequest event to re-attach the eventhandlers.